# "Necessary" and "should" in English grammar

Tags: grammar

In modern English, is the "should" in the following sentence grammatically appropriate? It seems redundant to me:

> It's necessary that you should be prepared for the worst.

It's important/vital/urgent instead of necessary work for me, but "necessary" and "should" seem redundant.

Comment: Which dialect? In American English you'd typically leave out the "should," but in British English you wouldn't.

Comment: @alphabet - This Brit would find _it is necessary to be..._ quite acceptable.

Comment: "should prepare" is probably better than "should be prepared", if you want the person to actively prepare rather than just sit around and hope someone else will supply them with the necessary.

Comment: I find  the "it is necessary ... you should" combination semantically jarring. **you should** expresses the idea of "it would be prudent of you" or "it is expected of you" whereas **It is necessary** goes a step further and makes it a mandate, a must.  *It is necessary that you be prepared* sounds fine to me, as does *You should be prepared*.

Comment: I would be more likely to say "You must be prepared" if it is meant to be necessary or "You ought to be prepared" if it is more a matter of prudence. "You must/ought to prepare" would be better if the action of preparing is what is being emphasized. The "It's necessary that" part seems clunky and redundant to me.

Comment: @KateBunting I mean that the mandative subjunctive ("It is necessary that you be prepared") is considerably more common in AmE than in other dialects.

Comment: @alphabet one would not leave out "should" in American English, typically. See https://www.stgries.info/research/2020_SCD-STG_SubjunctInWorldEngl_Corpora.pdf  

For instance, Algeo (1992: 612) reports that ‘[e]ven
“verbally impoverished” and “semiliterate” students of remedial English use
the mandative subjunctive because it is the norm in American English’.

Comment: @the_darkside The first source you cite proves exactly the point I'm trying to make; the table on p. 222 says that the mandative subjunctive is 7 times more common than the version with *should* in American English. (Note that the mandative subjunctive is the version without the *should.*)